# Can I create two seperate objects with two seperate vshadders and programs in Webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to create a circle in webgl, and then have the user click 3 times and a triangle appear where they clicked using LINE_LOOP. I created 2 vshaders and 2 programs, but after 3 clicks the circle dissapears. I tried declaring both programs in the main functions and then do everything with the buffers for the triangle in the click function. In the click function I find the x,y position of where the user clicks and then push those values onto a vertices array that i try to use to output the triangle. I'm pretty sure the logic of the function is mostly right because I have a similar function for another code I created in the past. I want the user to see the circle the whole time and then see a triangle created where they clicked after 3 clicks.

Here is my declaration of the shaders

```
        var circlevertices_length;
        var gl = null;
        var program = 0;
        var program2 = 0;
        var divisions = 0;
        var tcount = 0;
        var tmax = 3;
    
        var trivert = [
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0
            ];

        var VSHADER_SOURCE = `
       precision highp float;
           attribute vec3 coordinates;

        void main(){
               gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);
        }
        `;

        var VSHADER_SOURCE_TRIANGLE = `
             precision highp float;
             attribute vec3 coordinates2;

        void main() {
             gl_Position = vec4(coordinates2, 1.0);
         }
         `;

        var FSHADER_SOURCE = `
        precision highp float;
        uniform vec4 color;

        void main(){
         gl_FragColor = color;
        }
```

Here is my main function:

```
    function main(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCircle");
    gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    
    program1 = createProgram(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE);
    program2 = createProgram(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE_TRIANGLE, FSHADER_SOURCE);

    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    
    //register event handler to be called on a mouse click
        canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){
            click(ev, gl, canvas)
        };

    render();   
    
    return;
     }
```

Here is where I do everything to create the triangle:

```
    function click(ev, gl, canvas){
    gl.useProgram(program2);

    var x = ev.clientX;
    var y = ev.clientY;
    var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(tcount < tmax){
        x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)/(canvas.width/2);
        y = (canvas.height/2 - (y-rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);
        z = 0.0;

        trivert[tcount * 3 + 0] = x;
        trivert[tcount * 3 + 1] = y;
        trivert[tcount * 3 + 2] = z;

        tcount++;
    }

    if(tcount == tmax){
        alert(trivert[0],trivert[1],trivert[2])
        var buff = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buff);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trivert, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        const position_loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program2, "coordinates2");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position_loc);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(position_loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        const color_loc2 = gl.getUniformLocation(program2, 'color');
        gl.uniform4f(color_loc2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, tcount);

        gl.disableVertexAttribArray(position_loc);
        tcount = 0;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two different programs to do this, but rather two distinct buffers. And you must draw the circle everytime. Something like this:

```js
function paint() {
  gl.useProgram(prg)
  const position_loc = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "coordinates")
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position_loc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(position_loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, circleBuffer)
  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, circleVerticesCount)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer)
  gl.dataBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trivert, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, tCount)
}
```